# Bouncycastle: CertificateFactory.generateCertificate gives "sequence wrong size for a certificate" on one machine but not on another

Tags: certificate, bouncycastle

I’m trying to open a p7b file and read the CA certificates out of it. Below is my code. It works fine in one machine but in another machine the call to certFactory.generateCertificate throws exception

```
Error Message:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: sequence wrong size for a certificate
```

On both machines I have the same p7b file, and the same bouncycastle jars. The machine where is works is a Windows Xp and the one where it doesn’t work is a Windows 2007 server machine. It is a 64 bit machine but I’m using the 32 bit jvm only.

```
    CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509",
            new BouncyCastleProvider());
    java.security.cert.Certificate cert = null;
    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("");
    ArrayList<java.security.cert.Certificate> certificates = new ArrayList<java.security.cert.Certificate>();
    CAService caService = null;
    caService.getCertificateAuthority().setCaCerts(new ArrayList<String>());

    while ((cert = certFactory.generateCertificate(inStream)) != null)
    {
        certificates.add(cert);
        StringWriter swrtr = new StringWriter();
        PEMWriter writer = new PEMWriter(swrtr);
        writer.writeObject(cert);
        writer.flush();
        caService.getCertificateAuthority().getCaCerts().add(swrtr.toString());
    }
```

I even wrote a standalone program and I’m running even explicitly specifying the java.exe to use but I’m facing the same exception on that machine alone.

c:\jdk1.5.0_14\jre\bin\java.exe  -classpath .;bcprov-jdk15-143.jar MSCAConfigurator

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: sequence wrong size for a certificate
        at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKX509CertificateFactory.engineGenerateCertificate(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:271)
        at MSCAConfigurator.main(MSCAConfigurator.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: sequence wrong size for a certificate
        at org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509CertificateStructure.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509CertificateStructure.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKX509CertificateFactory.readPEMCertificate(Unknown Source)
```

I have the unlimited strength policy jars present.

C:\jdk1.5.0_14\jre\lib\security>dir *.jar

Volume in drive C has no label.

Volume Serial Number is D214-CB94

Directory of C:\jdk1.5.0_14\jre\lib\security

09/13/2004  04:12 PM             2,486 local_policy.jar

09/13/2004  04:12 PM             2,472 US_export_policy.jar

What’s wrong with this machine? Someone please help before I shoot myself.

Answer (score 2):

Cross-posted and apparently resolved the issue here http://www.coderanch.com/t/528193/Security/CertificateFactory-generateCertificate-gives-sequence-wrong

Answer (score 0):

According to the javadocs, `CertificateFactory.generateCertificates()` support the PKCS#7 format but `CertificateFactory.generateCertificate()` does not.